# Inside a class definition: How to perform a math operation on a class property?

Tags: powershell

I am finally delving into PowerShell classes and I have set out to create a TimeCode (Different from TimeSpan)

I want to add a `TotalMinutes` property. Inside the class, I tried `$This.$Hours * 60`, along with many other attempts:

```
class TimeCode {
    [int]$Hours
    [int]$Minutes
    [int]$Seconds
    [int]$Frames

    [int]$FrameRate
    
    # [int]$TotalMinutes = $This.Hours * 60
    # [int]$TotalMinutes = $Hours * 60
[int]$TotalMinutes = $This.$Hours * 60
    # [int]$TotalMinutes = $Hours * 60 + $Minutes
    # [int]$TotalMinutes = $This.Hours

}
```

But when I do:

```
$MyTimeCode = [TimeCode]::new()
$MyTimeCode.Hours   = 10
$MyTimeCode.Minutes = 5
$MyTimeCode.Seconds = 3

$MyTimeCode
```

I always end up getting the following:

```
Hours        : 10
Minutes      : 5
Seconds      : 3
Frames       : 0
FrameRate    : 0
TotalMinutes : 0
```

I am expecting `TotalMinutes` to have a value of `600` but it always has `0`
What gives?

---

Edit1:
@Mathias

I am not a programmer in the least bit, I am an animator so I deal with Time stamps quite often, cli tools, such as **Fffmpegs** (`-ss` and `-to` parameters) expect a time code string in the format `00:00:00.00`. I am trying to build a universal Type/Object that as well as letting me increment/decrement it precisely(either with minutes, seconds or frames), it will also pass a `00:00:00.00` string, to programs that expect it.

I am a long way from the end result but I imagine, it is something like this:

```
$SnippetStart = Timecode -M 10 -S 30 -FPS 12                                                #TimeCode is a function that returns "TimeCode" Type
FFMPEG -ss $SnippetStart` -to ($SnippetStart.AddFrames(300)) -i "C:\Temp\MyVideo.mp4"        #The AddFrames() method will calculate the new timecode using the objects "FPS" value the "TimeCode" type has
```

Learning classes in PowerShell is my primary goal. Hence the question of how to get `TotalMinutes` to respect the declaration order, so that it goes to the bottom, much like `[OrderedDictionary]` accelerator for HashTables. But this is not important anyways, I will revisit it as I learn more about classes.

Thank you for helping me, you and Santiago.

Comment: `$This.$Hours` is null and `0 * 60` is `0`. You meant to use `$this.Hours`.

Comment: PowerShell's class feature doesn't support custom property getters - all declared properties in a class definition essentially behave like _fields_. You could add a `GetTotalMinutes()` method

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I tried this again just now, it does not seem to do anything either.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen what do you mean by they behave like "fields"?

Comment: You can assign values to them, and you can read assigned values from them - but you can't [override accessors individually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties#the-get-accessor)

Comment: [GitHub issue #2219](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2219) is the (very old) feature request asking for PowerShell classes to support property getters.

Comment: @mklement0 I am quite surprised this is not so possible directly. If I am not mistaken, this is the equivalent of inside functions, parameter variables not being accesible to other parameter variables. I will have to pay the PowerShell team at Github a visit. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to add a TotalMinutes property. Inside the class, I tried $This.$Hours * 60, along with many other attempts:

PowerShell's class feature doesn't support custom property getters - all declared properties in a class definition essentially behave like fields.

You could add a `GetTotalMinutes()` method:

```
class TimeCode {
    [int]$Hours
    [int]$Minutes
    [int]$Seconds
    [int]$Frames

    [int]$FrameRate

    [int]
    GetTotalMinutes() {
        return $this.Hours * 60 + $this.Minutes
    }
}
```

```
PS ~> $timeCode = [TimeCode]@{Hours = 10; Minutes = 5; Seconds = 3}
PS ~> $timeCode.GetTotalMinutes()
603
```

---

Another option is to make each instance attach ETS members to itself in the constructor:

```
class TimeCode {
    [int]$Hours
    [int]$Minutes
    [int]$Seconds
    [int]$Frames

    [int]$FrameRate

    TimeCode () {
        $this |Add-Member -Name TotalMinutes -MemberType ScriptProperty -Value {
            return $this.Hours * 60 + $this.Minutes
        } -SecondValue { throw 'Property "TotalMinutes" is ReadOnly' }
    }
}
```

Beware that the `$this` auto-variable inside the scriptblock passed to `Add-Member -Value` is *not* the same variable as the `$this` auto-variable inside the class constructor - even though the former will eventually reference the latter :)

---

If the purpose is to collect information to pass to `ffmpeg` in a certain format, consider adding a method that'll produce the exact command line arguments required:

```
class TimeCode {
    [int]$Hours
    [int]$Minutes
    [int]$Seconds
    [int]$Frames

    [int]$FrameRate

    [string[]]
    ToFFMPEGArgs([int]$FrameCount, [string[]]$Files) {
        $startTime = New-TimeSpan -Hours $this.Hours -Minutes $this.Minutes -Seconds $this.Seconds
        $duration = New-TimeSpan -Seconds $($FrameCount / $this.FrameRate)
        $stopTime = $startTime.Add($duration)

        return @(
            '-ss'
            $startTime.ToString('hh\:mm\:ss\.fff')
            '-to'
            $stopTime.ToString('hh\:mm\:ss\.fff')
            $Files.ForEach({ '-i', "'$_'"})
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
PS ~> $timeCode = [TimeCode]@{ Hours = 0; Minutes = 10; Seconds = 15; FrameRate = 24 }
PS ~> $ffmpegArgs = $timeCode.ToFFMPEGArgs(300, @("C:\Temp\MyVideo.mp4"))
PS ~> & ffmpeg @ffmpegArgs
```

Comment: I appreciate both examples and I am sure I will come to need them not long. I intend to pass parts or the whole of this object to tools like FFMPEG in a conformed generic manner, so I dont think a method will help here. The second example is ideal but like Santiago, the `TotalMinutes` appears first now. Is it possible to make it show last?

Comment: @Ralf_Reddings Nothing comes to mind. Can you tell a bit more about why that's a problem? How are you planning on turning these objects into string input for `ffmpeg`? Perhaps adding a `ToFFMPEGArgs()` method that produces the required string would suffice?

Comment: Its not so important, I just wanted to know it as I am learning classes but since I troubled you with it, I feel that I owe you an expalanation. I made an edit in my OP.

Comment: @Ralf_Reddings You forgot to show what `FFMPEG -ss $SnippetStart` is meant to expand to - what's the information and format required by the `-ss` option?

Comment: `-to` and `-ss` both require a time stamp in the format `HH:MM:SS:` or `HH:MM:SS.MS` My object is also supposed to have a property called `TimeStamp`, which is also `HH:MM:SS.MS`. I have not figured it out yet but this property is whats supposed to expand in the case of `FFMPEG -ss $SnippetStart`

Comment: @Ralf_Reddings Gotcha. I added an example of one way to encode the whole argument-transformation step in a class method :)

Answer (score 2):

The first issue was noted by [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen):

> PowerShell's class feature doesn't support custom property getters - all declared properties in a class definition essentially behave like fields. You could add a `GetTotalMinutes()` method.

Following this thought, you could also add a [`PSScriptProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psscriptproperty?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) while instantiating your class (see demo blow) which serves the purpose of a [*getter property*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties#the-get-accessor).

The second issue, is `$This.$Hours` when it should be `$This.Hours`. `$Hours` does not exist in the context of your class and the expression `$This.$Hours` would result in `$null`.

```bash
class TimeCode {
    [int]$Hours
    [int]$Minutes
    [int]$Seconds
    [int]$Frames
    [int]$FrameRate

    TimeCode() {
        $this.PSObject.Members.Add(
            [psscriptproperty]::new('TotalMinutes', { $this.Hours * 60 }))
    }
}

$MyTimeCode = [TimeCode]::new()
$MyTimeCode.Hours = 50
$MyTimeCode.TotalMinutes # 3000
$MyTimeCode.Hours = 10
$MyTimeCode.TotalMinutes # 600
```

Comment: This works, but it seems to mess with the order I need the properties to be in. When I print `$MyTimeCode` object, the `TotalMinutes` property is always shown first. Is it possible to respect the declaration order in the class? Cheers.

Comment: @Ralf_Reddings I don't think it is possible to change the order with a powershell class.